# Setting up an nginx configuration to have all domains go to one server block, except one

Tags: nginx, hosts

What would need to be done to achieve the following server configuration?

abc.com, def.com, ghi.com, and all others pointed to this IP -> server block A.

specialdomain.com *only* -> server block B.

I've tried creating two server blocks, one with server_name localhost with listen 8080 default, another with server_name specialdomain.com with listen 8080, but it's piping all of the requests to the first server block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set up one specific nginx conf block for `specialdomain.com`, then have a general catch-all nginx config block for the rest.

One block should have the `server_name` set to `www.specialdomain.com specialdomain.com`, and the other block should have it set to `localhost`.